# How can I buy government bonds from foreign countries?

Tags: international, government-bonds

I would like to follow the advice of Nassim Nicholas Taleb, to a little degree. I have retirement money in lots of US domestic stock funds which is also where I live. I would like to hold some government treasuries in countries other than the US. I would not want to hold all my savings pegged to one country. What is the most efficient way to buy treasuries from all over the world weighted for the size of the economy of that country. Is there anything such as a basket of international treasuries. I also thought of simply randomly selecting 4 countries (random since I do not believe I know the future, and nor do you) with the weighting based on GDP. So if I spin my random selector...Argentina, China, Italy and Poland come up. I could buy bonds and in say 3 years time sell them and go for another spin of the random generator.

Please save me from my naivite!

Comment: What advice are you referring to? Have you considered mutual funds?

Comment: Are there mutual funds whose cost is close to zero and whose objective is to simply index (mirror) government bonds weighted to the size of the conuntry's economy AND excludes US bonds? I wand to know the cheapest and most efficient way of buying international government bonds directly or an instrument that will achieve same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Significantly less effort to buy into any of several international bond index funds. Off the top of my head, VTIBX.

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of thing. Quoting from their Product summary, `This fund is designed to provide broad exposure to non-U.S. investment-grade bonds. The fund seeks to track the performance of an index that includes international government, agency, and corporate securities, mostly from developed countries, but also some emerging markets countries. `